# How to save configurable product with its attributes in magento 2

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, magento2.2.2

I wish to save  product with its attributes. I have tried below code,It works fine while saving simple products. but if i gave configurable product sku in my csv file, then  it shows an error as

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\InputException: Option values are not specified.
```

**Please proovide me a solution to save configurable product with its attributes**

**strong text**
myfile.php

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$file = 'csv/test.csv';
$headers = false;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if (empty($handle) === false) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        if ($row[0] == 'sku')
            continue;
        // get all the attibute and options
        $sku = $row[0];
        $color = $row[1];
        $colorAttrOptionId = getAttrOptionId('color', $color, $objectManager);
        $productId = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getIdBySku($sku);
        $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
        $_product->setColor($colorAttrOptionId);
        $_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
        $_product->save();
    }
}
fclose($handle);
echo "Sucess";

function getAttrOptionId($attributeCode, $attributeLabel, $objectManager)
{

    $eavConfig = $objectManager->get('Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute');
    $attributeId = $eavConfig->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
    $attr = $objectManager->get('Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute')->load($attributeId);
    $attributeType = $attr->getFrontendInput();

    $attroptionid = array();
    if ($attr->usesSource()) {
        if (strpos($attributeLabel, ',')) {
            $multiselectLabel = explode(',', $attributeLabel);
            foreach ($multiselectLabel as $multiselect) {
                $multiattroptionid = $attr->setStoreId(0)->getSource()->getOptionId($multiselect);
                $attroptionid [] = $multiattroptionid;
            } return $attroptionid;
        } else {
            if ($attributeType == 'multiselect') {
                $optionid = $attr->setStoreId(0)->getSource()->getOptionId($attributeLabel);
                $attroptionid = $optionid;
                return $attroptionid;
            } else if ($attributeType == 'select') {
                $attrbuteoptionid = $attr->setStoreId(0)->getSource()->getOptionId($attributeLabel);
                return $attrbuteoptionid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

csv file

[image]

**[image: Array of my csv file]**